# Creating an Index Column for a Descriptive Data Using "DAX" in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table Like this,

*Table1*

```
ColA   ColB
Orange Apple
Mango  Not Apple
Mango  Not Apple
```

I want to create a column called as RowNumber using DAX and not Query Editor (M).

So the Expected output is,

```
ColA     ColB        RowNumber
Orange   Apple       1
Mango    Not Apple   2
Mango    Not Apple   3
```

This can be done in M - Power Query Side.

But, I am looking for a solution using DAX- Calculated Column.

I expected functions like RowNumber (T-SQL) or Index to be present inside DAX.

Comment: What column do you want to sort by?

Comment: Nothing Specific. Everything like that is done on the Query Editor. But, if you need one - Take ColA

Answer (score 5):

If you need to create an Index in DAX you can use this formula:

```
Index = RANKX(ALL(Barges),Barges[Date],,ASC)
```

RANKX: create your Index values

ALL:   to avoid your Index to be partially generated if you have any filter

The second parameter is from where you want to sort your data, in my example I have an Index number increasing with an ascending order on my date, if I use Barges[name] instead for example I'll have my index generating with an A-Z sorting on my barges names.

Comment: Excellent solution