# Plot a "path" in powerBI without R / python

Tags: powerbi

For a dashboard, I need to create an "interactive" plot of a shape. This shape is defined by a set of points X/Y but not always sorted on X (on purpose). However, it seems that Power BI is always performing the sort leading to the wrong shape. For example with those points:

```
X   Y
0   10
5   10
6   12
7   12
6.5 8
10  6
12  4
11  0
```

I was expecting :

[image: expected]

But instead I have with line chart:

[image: result]

I've looked into the line chart option without success and also in the marketplace. Is there a workaround ? I'd be surprised that power BI does not have the capability for such a small thing.

If there is no option, is there something else I could look at in order to have the plot with capability to zoom ? I saw that we cannot use plotly on power BI (https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Use-Plotly-with-Python-Script-in-Power-BI/td-p/720797). Is that still actual in version January 2020 ?

Many thanks,

Nicolas

Comment: Create an index column, example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55363055/creating-an-index-column-for-a-descriptive-data-using-dax-in-power-bi then sort X by 'sort by another column' to preserve the data order

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I was exactly thinking about that. I've added an index column but on the plot, I can't see any `sort by another column`. I have Power BI Desktop January 2020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your example data, create an index column. You need to do it in Power Query, as it may result in a circular reference if you do it in DAX.

[image]

Make the axis sort by this new column, using the 'Sort by column' feature and selecting the new index.

[image]

Which should give you

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot :). I was on the right track but did not realized that the sorting is different for each column and has to be applied specifically on X.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same task, but my x values contain duplicates. It prevents these x values from sorting the way it is described above.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbqXR.png)

How possible is it to find a solution in this situation?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).